# Error using Swift - Instance member cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to make an app in Xcode 7 using Swift and I'm trying to convert numbers inside a textfield to an integer using this code, `let a = Int(percentLabel.text!)`

But everytime I try this I get an error that says `Instance Member 'percentLabel' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, maybe it's a bug which I've already found in Xcode 7.

Here is my full code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tipSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var splitSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var billAmount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var totalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var tipTotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var totalPerPerson: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var percentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var splitLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    let a = Int(percentLabel.text!)

    @IBAction func tipChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        let currentValue = Int(tipSlider.value)
        percentLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }

    @IBAction func splitChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        let currentValue = Int(splitSlider.value)
        splitLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }

    @IBAction func amountChanged(sender: AnyObject) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code returns a new value every time you call it. I expect it what you're looking for

```
var myInt: Int? {
    return Int(percentLabel.text!)
}
```

instead of

```
let myString = percentLabel
let myInt: Int? = Int(myString)
```

Answer (score 12):

You cannot have these two lines outside of a function call in a class

```
let myString = percentLabel
let myInt: Int? = Int(myString)
```

You cannot intialise a property to a value of another property, you cannot set a variable's default value to that of another property. you would usually do this in a function like viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. Arsen's answer should also work as it will try to get the value lazily, or as you request it.

`let myString = percentLabel` would also not return the text, you'd need to do `let myString = percentLabel.text` but you cannot assign this value like a property. you'll need to put his code in the body of a function

Comment: I made a change to the code, instead of of let myString = percentLabel
let myInt: Int? = Int(myString) I meant to have let a = Int(percentLabel.text!) which gives me the same error. I would appreciate if you could explain it a bit more because I am not experienced in Swift or programming

Comment: I've updated the answer. It's just because you are creating a property on the class that depends on a value of another property. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Actually, I think I've gotten it figured out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Arsens answer should do the trick for you in this case. otherwise it would depend on WHEN you want the value set.