# Error : Instance member cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, instance

I created a subclass of `UIView` below :

```
import UIKit

class MenuBar : UIView {

    override init(frame : CGRect ){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
       }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
      }
    func setupViews(){

      }
}
```

then, I want to add it to my `ViewController` :

```
let menuBarView : MenuBar = {

        let mbv = MenuBar(
        mbv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mbv.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return mbv
    }()
```

But it return an error : 
instance member 'MenuBar' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error using Swift - Instance member cannot be used on type 'ViewController'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055147/error-using-swift-instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure, but your code should not even compile as your lazy variable instantiation of menubar says

```
let mbv = MenuBar(
```

Which it should be

```
let mbv = MenuBar()
```

Final working code would be

```
let menuBarView : MenuBar = {

        let mbv = MenuBar()
        mbv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mbv.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return mbv
    }()
```

Tested it, it works absolutely fine.

**EDIT:**

This is how am using it and it is working fine!

```
//other variable declaration
    let menuBarView : MenuBar = {
        let mbv = MenuBar()
        mbv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mbv.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return mbv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(menuBarView)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Comment: I dont find any issue!! Tried all possibilities, Can you please post little more code, where are you creating your lazy variable ?? How are you using it in your VC

Comment: sorry my english is not good so i can't explain you more clearly.
* In that project :  class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource 
=> so it's return error
* I try on a new project : class ViewController : UIViewController
=> no error

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault, MenuBar class possible duplicate of another class in another swift file so that return error =) tks for your attention. 
I'm going to vote for you.
Thanks again